# ESP8266 and Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am trying to upload a sketch and getting below error:
Except the usual connection my GPIO 0 is grounded.

```
Arduino: 1.8.1 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, 40MHz,
DOUT, 115200, 512K (64K SPIFFS), ck, Serial1, All"

Sketch uses 232813 bytes (53%) of program storage space. Maximum is 434160 bytes
Global variables use 34092 bytes (41%) of dynamic memory, leaving 47828 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

error: failed reading byte

warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data

warning: espcomm_sync failed

error: espcomm_open failed

error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Comment: How to wire hardware is not a programming problem, which means it's off-topic.

Comment: Ask here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and add schematic.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a bad connection. I recommend that you follow this scheme that I leave here.

[ESP01 connection with Arduino UNO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx0QC.png)

You can also consult this complete guide on the ESP01 (https://programarfacil.com/podcast/como-configurar-esp01-wifi-esp8266/) that although it is in Spanish, is very simple to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure GPIO 0 is grounded, and then reset the ESP8266. Also make sure you have 3.3v coming in to CH_PD and RST. Set baud rate to 115200 unless you changed it already.